# How to get the list of non-attached ec2 Ebs volume across regions

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

```
public class EbsVolume {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("AKI********", "p0v********");
        AmazonEC2 ec2 = AmazonEC2ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
                .build();


            List<Volume> volumes = null;
            String volumeID = "";

            DescribeVolumesRequest req = new DescribeVolumesRequest();
            req.setMaxResults(20);
            DescribeVolumesResult result = ec2.describeVolumes(req);
            if (result != null && !result.getVolumes().isEmpty()) {
                volumes = result.getVolumes();

                //log.info("Page Size : " + volumes.size());
            }
            for (Volume e : volumes) {
                volumeID = e.getVolumeId();
                System.out.println(volumeID);
            }     

    }

}
```

Above code is the sample code for retrieving the list of ebs volumes for the specific region but I require to fetch from all regions in a single call and as well only non-attached ebs volumes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to fetch from all regions in a single call, so your requirement can not be met. The best you can do is create a loop that iterates through each region, making the call once per region.

Comment: Hi mark, I already tried by iterating each region and set it to clientbuilder. but i am getting Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.AmazonEC2Exception: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 401; . because once i set the credentials to clientbuilder its immutable .. how do i overcome with this problem by setting many regions

Comment: How about including the code that does the loop in your question so we can see what you are doing wrong? Worst case you could simply build a new EC2 client object in each iteration of the loop, instead of trying to reuse one instance.

Comment: Hi mark, i have only one client builder and i iterated regions one by one and set it to that client builder ..

Comment: @ramp What is stopping you from creating a new client object each time? There's no rule that you can only have one client builder.

Comment: Hi mark , thanks .. So now i understood that if i want to do same operations on 19 regions so i have to create 19 client builder?

Comment: You understand how to program a loop right? You would technically be creating 19 client builders, but it would only be one line of code.

Comment: Yes mark i understood how to program a loop.. i created 19 clientbuilder and put it in a list then i iterated one by one ... below is the code i have ... but is there any other shortway of writing 19 clicent builder in one line ?. AmazonEC2 ec2 = AmazonEC2ClientBuilder
    .standard()
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
    .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
    .build();
  AmazonEC2 ec2West = AmazonEC2ClientBuilder
    .standard()
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
    .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_1)
    .build();

Comment: Hi Mark, initially I did the same thing I loop through regions.. So why I got the error at the beginning.. Once you set region for one client builder then its immutable